# Is this a linear transformation? in the context of group representations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

> Let $G$ be a group. A regular representation is given as $V=\mathbb{C}[G]$, a vector space, where $l: G \to GL(V)$ be the action is given by $l(g)(\alpha)(h) = \alpha (g^{-1}h)$ for all $g,h\in G, \alpha \in V$.

The professor asked us to find a trivial sup-representation for the sub-representation $U=\{ \alpha \in V | \sum_{g\in G}{\alpha(g) = 0}\}$.

What I did, is define a trivial linear transformation $\pi_0 : V\to U$ (and here is my question, is this really a linear transformation from $V$ to $U$?) $\pi_0(v) = 0$ if $v \notin U$ and $\pi_0(v) = v$ if $v \in U$, and then normalized it.

Comment: What do you mean by "normalized"?

Comment: It is not really my question, but we had a theory that if $\pi_0 : V \to U$, then to find a subrepresentation we normalize $\pi_0$ by defining $\pi(v) = \frac{1}{|G|} \pi'(v)$ where $\pi'(v) = \sum_{g \in G} {g^{-1}\pi_0(gv)}$, and $W=Ker(\pi)$ is a sub-representation. My question is, was $\pi_0$ a linear transformation?

Comment: Note that because $U$ is a subrepresentation, $g^{-1}\pi_0(gv)=\pi(v)$ for all $v\in V$, so actually $\pi'=\pi_0$.

Comment: @EricWofsey, Thanks, but that was not my original question. Is $\pi_0$ a linear transformation from $V$ to $U$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\pi_0$ is not linear (unless $G$ is trivial so $U=0$ and $\pi_0=0$).  For instance, let $u\in U$ and $v\in V\setminus U$ be any two nonzero vectors.  Then $u+v\not\in U$ (otherwise $v=(u+v)-u$ would be in $U$), so $\pi_0(u+v)=0\neq u=\pi_0(u)+\pi_0(v)$.